# equal det $\begin{bmatrix} 7 & 2 & 1\\ -9 & 0 & 2\\ 8 & 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 2\\ 1 & 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Note: If you find a special reason, then I may consider unchecking the current answer and checking an answer you would post.

---

Is there any special reason why $\begin{bmatrix}
7 & 2 & 1\\ 
-9 & 0 & 2\\ 
8 & 2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 2 & 1\\ 
0 & 0 & 2\\ 
1 & 2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$ have the same determinant of 4? See for yourself: [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=%7B%7B7%2C2%2C1%7D%2C%7B-9%2C0%2C2%7D%2C%7B8%2C2%2C1%7D%7D) and [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=%7B%7B0%2C2%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C2%7D%2C%7B1%2C2%2C1%7D%7D).

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What sort of answer are you expecting?  This is like asking if there is any special reason why $17+23$ and $2\times 13+14$ are equal.  They happen to evaluate to the same number... what more do you want from that?  We could tell you that the one matrix can be transformed into the other via elementary row operations... but that is true of any matrices of same size with the same nonzero determinant and is not special in any way.

Comment: Here, rather than row operations, column operations to explain this looks to be quicker, noticing that the second and third columns are the same for both.  Replacing the first column with the first column plus an appropriate linear combination of the other columns... this doesn't change the determinant.

Comment: @JMoravitz i was thinking like those counting formulas where you can prove equality of 2 permutations/combinations by counting something in 2 different ways. i've forgotten those rules of elementary matrices, so eh.

Comment: @JMoravitz oh wait actually the 2nd and 3rd columns are the same. i forgot about that.. Edit: oh ok never mind thanks

Comment: If the alternatives are limited to "Answer in a comment" and "Not answer", the second option is better. It doesn't matter how much you've seen it. The comment box says you shouldn't do it and it's bad for the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the last two columns are the same for the two matrices.  Start with $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 2 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 2\\ 1 & 2 & 1\end{bmatrix}$. Add $23/4$ times the second column to the first column.  Add $-9/2$ times the third column to the first column.  The result is $\begin{bmatrix}7 & 2 & 1\\ -9 & 0 & 2\\ 8 & 2 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.  Therefore, the two matrices have the same determinant.